# aggregation and group in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am getting below documents after my $project , but now I need to find out the average of the transactions.
Below are the documents after my '$project', before '$group'

```
{
  "name" : "AAA",
  "transactions" : [
     {
        "amount" : 500000
     },
     {
        "amount" : 12700000
     },
     {
        "amount" : 27500000
     }
   ]
}
{
 "name" : "BBBB",
 "transactions" : [
     {
        "amount" : 2500000
     },
     {
        "amount" : 5500000
     },
     {
        "amount" : 18000000
     }

 ]
}
{
  "name" : "CCCC",
  "transactions" : [
      {
        "amount" : 10000000
      },
      {
        "amount" : 5000000
      },
      {
        "amount" : 1000000
      }

  ]
}
```

I tried something like this.

```
 {$group:{"_id":"$name", average:{$avg:"$transactions.amount"}}}
```

I am printing name values in _id field but the 'average' is printing 'null'

here is the output I am getting

```
{ "_id" : "AAA", "average" : null }
{ "_id" : "BBB", "average" : null }
{ "_id" : "CCC", "average" : null }
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with you **$group** stage on the aggregation framework, is that there is nothing to sum up to make an average. I mean, you are working around the "pure" array of values, but the $avg expression is not intelligent enough to sum up all the content of the array. You are trying to get an average of the array as a whole. The correct way to achieve this is doing an **$unwind** on a previous stage so you got documents like this

```
{
  "name" : "AAA",
  "transactions" : {"amount" : 500000}
}
{
  "name" : "AAA",
  "transactions" : {"amount" : 12700000}
}
{
  "name" : "AAA",
  "transactions" : {"amount" : 27500000}
}
```

now, you can do your **$group** stage that should look like

```
{$group:{"_id":"$name", average:{$avg:"$transactions.amount"}}}
```

this will make an average for each element contained in the transactions array that you $unwind before to have a document for each of the member.

I think you are taking a mongodb course on mongo university, good luck!